# Regular Expression TSQL

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

In a T-SQL Database I have this varchar attribute `nvarchar(512)`.

Its contains

```
Optj. på KU til=18-07-2014 00:00:00 enheder=15
```

Can I extract the date in a datetype variable using regular expressions?

Can I use the expression in Report Designer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server i would use of `substring()` with `patindex()` function to find date from `nvarchar` data

```
select substring(data, patindex('%[=]%', data)+1, 10)
```

Result:

```
18-07-2014
```